# does subscript evaluate before the right hand side of assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do something like

`arr[getchar()-'a'] = getchar();`

is it guaranteed that the subscript here evaluates before anything else?

Comment: Maybe think about doing `char c = getchar(); arr[c-'a'] = c;` and avoid confusion?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Your version has a different meaning to the original, `getchar` should be called twice.

Comment: Do you mean ... typing `"bc[<ENTER>]"` guarantees `arr[1] = 'c';` (as opposed to `arr[2] = 'b';`)?

Comment: Which language? Which standard?

Comment: @pmg Or worse. Unsequenced access is UB if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @john of course, I was just wondering if that's what they mean or no

Comment: See C++'s ["Order of evaluation"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) (here for [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order)).

Comment: @Jarod42 I think it would be best to detail both before and after the recent change in an answer. Which sounds like there should be a dupe.

Comment: [OT]:`'a'..'z'` are not guaranteed to be contiguous, so  ``getchar()-'a'`` is not portable.

Comment: @jarod42 GNU G++11

Comment: In C++17 it is guaranteed that the RHS of `=` is sequenced before the LHS, so the indexing `getchar()` is the second call. There is no such rule in C or before C++17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before C++17, no guaranty of order

**Since** C++17: (from [C++'s order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order))

> 17) In a subscript expression E1[E2], every value computation and side-effect of E1 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2
>
> 20) In every simple assignment expression E1=E2 and every compound assignment expression E1@=E2, every value computation and side-effect of E2 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E1

So in your case:

```
   arr[getchar()-'a'] = getchar();
// (2)  (3)              (1)
```

Comment: I updated my answer and referred to yours to avoid redundancy :-) Good point, didn't know about this change in C++17 - +1!

Answer (score 3):

**No, it's not guaranteed.** (at least for pre-C++17 code, [as others mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57303934/1753435)).

As by the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) rules (emphasis mine):

> **Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of
>   evaluation of function arguments is unspecified [...].
>   The compiler can evaluate operands and other
>   subexpressions in any order, and may choose another order when the
>   same expression is evaluated again.**
>
> There is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in
>   C++. This is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left
>   associativity of operators: the expression a() + b() + c() is parsed
>   as (a() + b()) + c() due to left-to-right associativity of operator+,
>   but the function call to c may be evaluated first, last, or between
>   a() or b() at run time

I'm quoting the C++ reference here, but [the same holds for C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order rule 20 says that there is a order for `=` since C++17.

Comment: C++17 saw some changes to sequencing introduced for certain expressions. The accuracy of this answer for that particular expression depends on the OP's choice of standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller and mch: Thanks for noting, I didn't know about the updated rules for C++17 - learning every day...